# Java EE show how many connections left in the connection pool

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oracle11g, oracle10g, connection-pooling

My system encounter some connection leak in connection pool. I would like to list down some statistic of the connection pool regularly, how can I do that? For example, Current Capacity, Active Connections High Count, Connections Total Count, Leaked Connection Count and etc.

I am using `javax.sql.DataSource` to retrieve the connection from connection pool. But I couldn't find any interface that can retrieve those connection pool information. Any ideas?

I am using Oracle DB and `Java EE` as my server side script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javax.sql.DataSource` is an interface and it just abstracts a data source. It does not involve providing pooled connections to it.

A connection pool is responsible for providing pooled, reusable connections to a database (data source).

First you need to find out which connection pool you're using. Connection pool implementations usually provide a way to query things like the number of active connections.

For example the Apache DBCP has a [BasicDataSource](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.html) class which is a connection pool, and it has a methods for this:

```
BasicDataSource.getMaxTotal();
BasicDataSource.getNumActive();
BasicDataSource.getNumIdle();
BasicDataSource.getMinIdle();
BasicDataSource.getMaxIdle();
```

Since you mentioned you're using Oracle DB, most likely your connection pool is [OracleOCIConnectionPool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleOCIConnectionPool.html) (part of Oracle JDBC driver) which provides:

```
OracleOCIConnectionPool.getMaxLimit();
OracleOCIConnectionPool.getPoolSize();
OracleOCIConnectionPool.getActiveSize();
OracleOCIConnectionPool.getMinLimit();
```